# Is there other way to implement search function without elasticsearch in Java

Tags: java, mysql, search

I am a newbie developer for web server side. I have develop an app for shop to manage their orders.  Here comes a question. 
I have an order table like:

`orderId，orderNumber …`

orderProduct table like

`orderProductId, productId, productNumber, productName, productDescription.`

I have a search function, that get all orders by searchString. 
The api is like

`Get /api/orders?productNumberSearch={searchStr}&productNameSearch={searchStr2}&productDescriptionSearch={searchStr3}`

My Impl is like

```
String queryStr1 = getParameterFromRequestWithDefault(“productNumberSearch”,”");
String queryStr2 = getParameterFromRequestWithDefault(“productNameSearch”,”");
String queryStr3 = getParameterFromRequestWithDefault(“productDescriptionSearch”,”");
List<OrderProduct> orderProducts = getAllOrderProductsFromDatabase();
List<Interger> filterOrderIds = orderProducts.stream().filter(item->{ 
    return item.getName().contains(queryStr1) && item.getNumber().contains(queryStr2) &&  item.getDescription().contains(queryStr3)
 }).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Order> orders = getOrdersByIds(filterOrderIds);
```

I use spring mvc and mysql. Codes above works. However,  if there are many requests arriving at the same time, out of memory exception will be thrown.  Case there are Chinese character in database , mysql full text search does not work well?
So is there other way to implement  the search function without elasticsearch

Comment: _" there are Chinese character in database , mysql full text search does not work well"_ sounds like you've got a charset / collation issue

Comment: There is solr, sphinx and other search engines.

Comment: @danblack thx, is it possible to do searching with out Search Engine?

Comment: yes, you can always use the wrong tools for the job. Doesn't mean its a good idea. Search engines do searching well, MySQL does relational databases well, Java does applications Ok. You don't use MySQL as an application server and you shouldn't do much more than basic full text searching with it.